# Eigenvalue of Unitary Matrix Interpolation within Unit Disk?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given unitary matrices $A$ and $B$ of same size. For $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$, are the magnitudes of all eigenvalues of $\alpha A+(1-\alpha)B$ less or equal 1?

So far, I've found a solution via Theorem I in "On Eigenvalues Of Sums Of Normal Matrices" by
Helmut Wielandt ( http://msp.org/pjm/1955/5-4/pjm-v5-n4-p14-p.pdf ). But, result is far more detailed than what I need to answer the question above. Do you have a more elementary proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $\alpha A + (1-\alpha)B$, and let $\lambda$ be the corresponding eigenvalue. Then
$$
|\lambda v| = |\alpha Av + (1-\alpha)Bv| = \sqrt{(\alpha|Av|)^2 + 2\alpha(1-\alpha)\Re(Av, Bv)+((1-\alpha)|Bv|)^2} \leq 
\sqrt{(\alpha|Av|)^2 + 2\alpha(1-\alpha)|Av||Bv|+((1-\alpha)|Bv|)^2} = \sqrt{(\alpha^2+2\alpha(1-\alpha)+(1-\alpha)^2)|v|^2} = |v|,
$$
since $|Av| = |Bv| = |v|$. So $|\lambda|\leq 1$.

Comment: That's nice. Thanks!